# Creating Test Accounts in Tezos

Tags: node

How do you create test net accounts in Tezos? Does it cost anything to create an account?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create test accounts on testnets or zeronet, you can use the [Tezos faucet](https://faucet.tzalpha.net/), it's free and you get fake tezzies for your tests :)